# Open new fragment or new activity with back arrow at top left while navigation drawer still working

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an app with a navigation drawer with fragment generated from android studio.

What I want is when I click the button, it opens a new view (fragment or activity) with back arrow at the top left while navigation drawer is still working.

like below screenshot:

[image][image]

I tried with a new blank activity, but there is no back arrow and navigation drawer is not working or gone.

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        Button button = root.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SlideshowActivity.class));
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
}
```

[image]

How i create like two screenshot above?

Comment: Please add the code and output design

Comment: Can you add toolbar in fragment with back arrow?

Comment: no while in fragment, my navigation drawer fragment is generated from android studio

Comment: Same question, how to mix Drawer and Navigation in Android? it's easy for iOS but really hard for Android

Comment: I think this post is useful for your question. I'm reading and answer if possible: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

Comment: @alfian5229 now I'm able to create like your 2 screenshots. Have you still need my answer?

Comment: @Tony not really, i forgot what project it is, but sure lets see your answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `SlideshowActivity` you need to set this in `onCreate` method

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And then, to handle the `back` action you need to do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // to close the activity
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: nice, but i cannot access navigation drawer

Comment: oh, sorry, if you wanna use the same navigation drawer, you need to use fragments. Your  second screenshot just have the `back` arrow, so the navigation drawer is not present there, I thought you wanna replicate that. Here's a tutorial of how to use nav drawer (it's a little long to put the code here) https://medium.com/android-hunger/how-to-implement-navigation-drawer-in-your-android-app-with-an-example-48e08530339f

Comment: the navigation drawer is generated from android studio, and working perfectly in HomeFragment, i can get navigation from left screen, but not in SlideShowActivity. So i need to change SlideShowActivty to fragment? how i call it on my button clicklistener?